# Drupal 7 front page issue.

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a drupal installation, which shows 2 different page when I enter the full domain (www.example.com ) and when I enter the full domain with /node ( www.example.com/node ).

When I put a new post, it shows up in "/node" url ( www.example.com/node ) but not when I enter the full domain.

When I login, admin bar also not visible for homepage and it's visible in every other page.

Answer (score 0):

In drupal there is theme template concept, for front-page in your current theme someone might have written code/rule to hide (admin bar) and other dynamic stuffs.

**Solution !**

Under your current theme check for **page--front.tpl** and within the file, check whether there is some code to override the admin bar and others things.

Reffer below URL for template information,

https://drupal.org/node/171194